# converting mddyy date to date

Tags: r, date, inquisit

I have a date column in a .csv spreadsheet generated in inquisit.

the format is `mddyy`, so the `13th of July` is `71315`. R recognizes this as an integer.

Can anyone recommend a way to convert this to `ISO 8601` date format?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I would like it as ISO 8601 e.g. "2015-07-13" but at the moment R does not even recognise it. I get the message 'Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format'

Comment: Is the day always two numbers? Like 7012015 would be July 1?

Comment: yes day is always two numbers. I assume when I get to October the month will also be two numbers but at the moment it is only 1. Also I made a mistake in the original question (which I have since edited); the year is two digits not four so '71315'

Answer (score 4):

Since you mention that the day is always two numbers, you could use a little `sprintf()` magic to add zeros out front.

```
as.Date(sprintf("%06d", 71315), "%m%d%y")
# [1] "2015-07-13"
```

The `sprintf()` call here adds zeros up to 6 characters and also turn it into a character vector, so `as.Date()` will accept it.

```
sprintf("%06d", 71315)
# [1] "071315"
```

Comment: thank you that worked beautifully. I'm not sure I understand what each character in the quotation marks denotes but it did work.

Comment: @llewmills - It's kind of hard to explain how it works, but you can find it in `help(sprintf)` about halfway down.  It's a descendant of the C function `printf()`

Answer (score 1):

We could also use `mdy` from `library(lubridate)`

```
library(lubridate)
mdy(71315) #returns POSIXct class.
#[1] "2015-07-13 UTC"
as.Date(mdy(71315)) #convert to `Date` class.
#[1] "2015-07-13"
```